# Web server subtracting 1 hour from dataset datetime for some days

Tags: web-services, datetime

We have a web server running Windows 2003 Standard and the time zone is set to GMT-06:00 Central Time, and the box is checked to adjust for daylight saving changes.

A web service on this server queries a datetime field and when the datetime is fetched it is correct. When the dataset is returned to the client 1 hour is subtracted from the datetime if the date is Mar 9-31, Apr 1-5, Oct 26-31, or Nov 1-5. These are the dates that the DST time change can happen on.

It does not matter when the data was saved to the database. If I save a date of 4/1/2013 today, it will be returned to the client minus the 1 hour.

We have verified that SQL is storing the date correctly since it is being returned to the web service correctly.

If I convert the date to a date string at the web server before returning it to the client, the correct date string is returned.

All dates outside of the possible DST dates are good.

All dates during DST that are not on a possible change date are good.

As an example, a date saved as 4/1/2013 12:00:00 AM will be returned as 3/31/2013 11:00:00 PM.

A date saved as 4/6/2013 12:00:00 AM will be returned as 4/6/2013 12:00:00 AM.

I added a web method to the web server to return a date value of Now() and it returns the correct date.

The only thing I have found that is similar was something about a XML rule that says all datetime values are to be transmitted using an offset. I'm not 100% sure but I don't think this is it because only some dates are changed.

Any thoughts/suggestions of what else to look at to get this resolved?

**Edit**: I have found some dates on the dates listed above that are correct.

Comment: @India Duncan came up with the answer - http://blog.scosby.com/post/2013/03/01/Serializing-A-DataSet-With-DateTime-Columns.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a shot at expanding this question, since i've had a similar issue in serialization of data objects.

Take a `System.DateTime` object that you want to write into a `DataColumn`. The `DateTime` object will by default return the `DateTime.Kind` property as [Unspecified]. When the `DataColumn` is then set to this `DateTime` object the `DataColumn` has a `DateTimeMode` property that resets to [UnspecifiedLocal].

There is not offest during serialization of `DataColumn` when the `DateTimeMode` is [Unspecified] or [UTC]. But when the `DateTimeMode` is set to [UnspecifiedLocal] or [Local], the offeset is applied. This is where the time can go up or down depending on the timezone or daylight savings configuration.

Sad news is that I can share your problem, but don't have a decent solution. Hope this helps your search.

I can only think of some ugly solutions, but i have not tested any. If i find an elegant solution i will try post again.